# Is there a proper way to check is a token is already used using FosUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, token, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FosUserBundle in order to reset a password by sending an e-mail and a confirmation token.

I configure the retry_ttl and token_ttl in config.yml to set the duration of the token.

```
fos_user:
...
resetting:
retry_ttl: 60 # Value in seconds, logic will use as hours
token_ttl: 86400
```

These parameters work well. But i want to add a paramter that check if a token is already used or not. I mean if the user has already clicked on the confirm e-mail, the token will be available one and only one time. Then it will be destroyed.
How may I process ?

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: It's already the case with fos user bundle...
confirmation token + password requested at fields are set to null when the reset of the password is completely done.
Did you tried to see what you have in DB?

Comment: Yes I saw that today in the morning. Thank you for your advice ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already the case with fos user bundle... 
Confirmation token + password requested at fields are set to null when the reset of the password is completely done.

PS: copy/pasted comment as an answer for future visibility